# how to get the text of a field in WPFormLite

Tags: php, wordpress, web, text, field

I have a form in my website (Wordpress) with several fields. I need to get the data from each field to process it in the logic of my program.
I have tried to use this code and other similar ones that they provide in their documentation but after 8 hours of work I have not succeeded.

Any ideas?

```
add_action("wpforms_process_complete", 'function_save_custom_form_data');

function function_save_custom_form_data($params) {

    foreach($params as $idx=>$item) {
        $field_name = $item['name'];
        $fiel_value = $item['value'];
        // Do whatever you need
        echo $field_name;
    }
    return true;
}
```